# Overfitting with epochs Mean squared error

Tags: data-science, artificial-intelligence, cross-validation, theory, overfitting-underfitting

If i am training my model and attempt to minimise MSE, if over a few epochs the MSE increases,
say

```
epoch 100, mse = 0.0992
epoch 101, mse = 0.0992
epoch 102, mse = 0.0994
epoch 103, mse = 0.0993
epoch 104, mse = 0.0992
epoch 105, mse = 0.0992
epoch 106, mse = 0.0991
...
...
```

if this happens at different stages does this imply over fitting?

Background:
I am using early stopping and if at any point the model accuracy goes up it will terminate, I want to know if this means that I should not use early stopping as it does not show overfitting?

Thank you

Comment: Are you using a gradient descent optimizer?

Comment: @ShivamMiglani yes im using Adam